# Проблема с созданием .jar файла в intelliJ - "No main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, maven

Сразу скажу, находил такие же вопросы тут, предлагаемые решения не помогли!
Есть **мавен** проект, там идет соединение с mySQL и т.д.
Пытаюсь создать исполняемый jar файл, но он не запускается, пишет

```
PS C:\Java\IdeaProgect\jdbc-exp\out\artifacts\jdbc_exp_jar> java -jar jdbc-exp.jar 
no main manifest attribute, in jdbc-exp.jar
```

в pom.xml указано

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc-exp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

В манифесте тоже все верно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Последовательность создания исполнительного jar файла File - Project Structure - Artifacts - (нажимаю плюсик) - JAR - From modules with dependencies - (выбираю Main Class, он у меня один)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жму ОК. Далее тут ничего не выбираю,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто жму Apply и OK. Затем Нажимаю Build - Build Artifacts - build

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Захожу в консоль и в итоге все равно пишет no main manifest attribute

Comment: Собирайте jar при помощи maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил следующим образом:

Добавил строку в pom.xml

```
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```